# Как реализовать OAuth 2.0 Authorization на Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Столкнулся с задачей реализации OAuth 2.0 на Flutter, где пользователь заходит через страничку сайта, а после получает authorization_code. Посоветуйте библиотеку. Или как это реализовать?

Answer (score 4):

[OAuth 2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2) от Dart Team, можно использовать на Flutter. В [документации](https://pub.dev/documentation/oauth2/latest/) все подробно расписано как использовать. Также можно использовать [Firebase Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth), но это немного другое.